# @ViewChild() from another component

Tags: angular

I have a component (component1) with the template:

```
<!-- component1.html -->
<ion-content #content></ion-content>
```

`<ion-content>` is an angular component. I need to get ion-content component from another component (component2).

In component1 I could do it using @ViewChild() directive:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-component1",
    templateUrl: "./component1.html"
})
export class Component1 {
    @ViewChild('content') content: IonContent;
    // or @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
}
```

but how to get ion-content component in Component2?

Comment: `@ViewChild()` searches for element in the DOM, so as long as the other component is in the DOM, you should be able to access it using template variable or the component class.
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: What is component2. And more important, what are you trying to achieve? You should very rarely access dom elements or sub components. Components collaborate with each other by the way of input, outputs and shared services.

Comment: Please follow the link: https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Answer (score 0):

in your **component1.html**

```
<ion-content #content></ion-content>
<p> this is {{message}}</p>
```

in your **component1.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-component1",
    templateUrl: "./component1.html"
})
export class Component1 {
    message: string;
    @ViewChild('content') content: IonContent;//or @ViewChild(IonContent)content:IonContent;

    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {    
    console.log(this.content.message);  //message being variable in IonContent
    this.message = this.content.message;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  }
}
```